# How to react on function that setting timeout

Tags: javascript, async.js

I have function:

```
function a(){ setTimeout(()=>{console.log('a')}, 0) }
```

This function send console.log on very end of callstack isn't it?

How can I write a function that runs after this console.log

the only way i found is send function on the of of callstack in the same way

```
a();
setTimeout(()=>{ console.log('after a'), 0 });
```

But it looks bad for me. I tried with promise, but i can react then on 'a' function not on console.log inside.

function 'a' is uneditable

Comment: Make a accept a callback and call it at the time you want: `function a(callback){ setTimeout(()=>{console.log('a'); callback?.()}, 0) }`, then `a(() => console.log('after a'));`.

Comment: Alternatively with a Promise: `function a(){ return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(()=>{console.log('a'); resolve()}, 0) ) }`, then use it like `a().then(() => console.log('after a'))`.

Comment: function 'a' is uneditable

Answer (score 0):

you can use "callback" , a reference to another function to the **a( )** function. Example:

```
function yourFunctionToBeRunnedAfter(){
..
..
}

function a(callback){ 
   setTimeout(()=>{
         console.log('a');
         calback();  // ==> here is your function execution.
    }, 0);
}

a(yourFunctionToBeRunnedAfter);
```

if you have parameters to pass to the **callback()** call, you can use **[apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)** or **[the spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** example:

```
function a(callback,...params){  // ... is the spread operator
   setTimeout(()=>{
         console.log('a');
         callback([...params]);  // ==> here is your function execution by spreading your params to the callback call.
    }, 0);
}
a(yourFunctionToBeRunnedAfter, 1,2,3);
```

Comment: in javascript you can override any object (function is an object) using prototyping or even without (in your case), example:
a = function(callback){
..
..
}

Comment: Its not the case. Its more like puzzle. In real world i know callbacks, promises, generatos, etc etc. Problem is what to do if you cant edit, or override function a.

Comment: if i was in your place,and the function is uneditable, i will use some tricks to copy the content/logic of the function reference to another projected reference, and manipulate it correctly. I don't think there is another solution if you don't use callbacks, promises, observables or even "[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)" object maybe helpful in your case. But to be honest, we still need more details about what you need..

Comment: I understand. It's a part of job interviev. I can't "cheat" like that. But i can't find other solution than make another timeout to put other function on the end on callstack.  But it seems to easy and unelegant. Im wondering is there better solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a promise. I'd recommend using async-await, but it really depends on your preference.

```
function a () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('a')
      resolve()
    }, 0)
  })
}

a().then(() => console.log('after a'))
```

If you need to know when timeouts finish often, I'd recommend making a helper function:

```
const wait = (time) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time))
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
(async () => {
  console.log('Hello')
  await wait(1000) // wait 1 second
  console.log('Hello a second later')
})()
```